# Angular select element's ngModel is incorrect

Tags: angular

When setting up a select html element with options added as view children, the select element outputs the option text instead of the options ngValue.

Follow this stackblitz for an example. Notice how 0 correctly outputs its option's ngValue, while 1,2,3 output their option's text.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngvalue-bug?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: What about if you use `value` instead of  `ngValue` ?

Comment: That's because the projected content cannot find the `ngModel` defined on the `select` element, because it's not in the same host element

Comment: @PierreDuc what would the fix be?

Comment: is  the output of 0 correct or the output of 1, 2, 3 is the one you expect to?

Comment: @Venusssss the output of 0

Comment: @Matt just use `[value]` instead of `[ngValue]`, this is only necessary if you want to use objects as value

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mre] **on this site**, not only on an external site.

Comment: @PierreDuc yes that would work but I need the output to be of type number not string. Also I will need an object as the value sometimes.